# Bootstrap Datepicker startdate on value

Tags: javascript, php, html, session

I would like to use a date from the session to disable all dates for the requested date.

I tried this :

This is the session with the date (dd-mm-yyyy)

```
 $_SESSION['beschikbaar'];
```

This is the input

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placehoder="End Date" value="<?php echo ''. $_SESSION['Beschikbaar'] . '' ?>" id="datepicker"/>
```

And this is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
        startDate: Date(val)
    });
});
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you want to disable specific date from session?

Comment: I want to disable all date before the session date. It's for a reservation script.

Comment: Check the code in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        currentDate = $("#datepicker").val();
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            startDate: currentDate
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: datetimepicker?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `datesDisabled` property of the datepicker.

For example

```
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
     startDate: Date(val),
     datesDisabled: ['<?php echo $_SESSION['beschikbaar']; ?>']
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vh1oknf7/250/

Also what exactly do you mean by "all dates for the requested date"? The `datesDisabled` property takes an array, if your session variable is an array of dates then each date will be blocked out. However, passing in 1 date will just block out this specific date.

Comment: If I tried that, my date picker will not work anymore. (I do not see the window anymore.)

Comment: quote marks needed for dateDisabled function. Try: 
`datesDisabled: ['<?php echo $_SESSION['beschikbaar']; ?>']`

Comment: Thanks @ImranAbdurRahim I missed that out

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
   minDate: new Date('<?php echo $_SESSION['beschikbaar']; ?>')
});
```